Treat the sum of residuals as scalar function for Gauss-Newton least squares regression
I have recently learned about Gauss-Newton method and puzzled about something. So given the model function $f(\vec{x}, \vec{\beta})$, and data points $(\vec{x_i}, y_i)$, the residuals are $S = \sum_{i} (y_i - f(\vec{x_i}, \vec{\beta}))^2 = \sum_{i} r_i^2$. Gauss-Newton utilizes Newton step $\vec{\beta_{t+1}} = \vec{\beta_{t}} - H^{-1}\vec{\nabla} S$ where Hessian is approximated with Jacobian $H=J^TJ$. The Jacobian matrix elements are $J_{ij} = \frac{dr_{i}}{d\beta_{j}}$, so essentially residuals are treated as multidimensional vector function ($r_1, r_2, ...$). Here comes my puzzle: if we treat $S$ as scalar function we may follow the same algorithm and now Jacobian is a vector $J_{j} = \frac{dS}{d\beta_{j}}$. However, clearly the Hessian approximation $H=J^TJ$ now is different (it is already obvious that it has rank 1). I don't see a reason why I can't apply Gauss-Newton to the whole scalar cost function but clearly it will not match the one applied to the vector function ($r_1, r_2, ...$). What is wrong with this?

@TedBlack, thanks for your comment! But I didn't get why it is stochastic gradient descent? I thought,  it is when at each iteration we optimize the cost function only for one or several training samples? Here I don't propose to throw away the training samples.

This is just a long comment.
What you are proposing is gradient decsent and not stochastic gradient descent (as you rightly point out stochastic gradient descent refers to using a single training sample). You can think of these three methods as the following minimizations:
Gradient descent minimizes
$$\frac{1}{2} \lVert \beta - \beta_t \rVert ^2 + \lambda (\beta - \beta_t)^\top \nabla S $$
Gauss-Newton minimizes
$$\lVert y - f(\beta_t)- J (\beta - \beta_t) \rVert^2 $$
i.e. turns the problem into standard least squares regression by using a linear approximation of $f$.  Note that since,
$$
S= \frac{1}{2} (y-f)^\top (y-f) 
$$
then,
$$
\nabla S = J^\top (y-f)
$$
Newton's method uses the second order approximation around $\beta_t$
$$
S(\beta)≈ S(\beta_t) + \nabla S (\beta - \beta_t) + \frac{1}{2}(\beta - \beta_t)^\top \nabla^2 S (\beta - \beta_t)
$$
and minimizes it w.r.t. $\beta$.

alright, so basically in Gauss-Newton we approximate the residuals linearly, which actually means that we linearly approximate the derivative of $S$., hence second order method. However, treating $S$ as scalar cost function just boils down to a conventional gradient descent. I think you resolved my conundrum.

@baronett thanks for marking my scribble as an answer. And yes, even with standard least squares ($f=X \beta$) we could use gradient descent to solve it but then this goes against the reason we formulated the problem as least squares.
